# Why does contenteditable="false" not work?

Tags: html-table, contenteditable

I have a C.R.U.D. app that builds many columns using PHP like this one below. This one is not meant to be editable by the user, only allowing a left click to display a dialogbox and a right click to run the function you see.
The issue is the field always opens allowing an entry, how do I prevent that, why is contenteditable="false" not preventing it? I need it to act more like a button than an editable field, but a button would be hard to fit in with the rest of the fields which are editable.
New edit: I tried using 'readonly' that prevented the  from opening but it also stopped both click events. I'm open to a redesign on the entire td but I need suggestions on how and what.

```
<?php
Echo ("
...
<td $brbCols contenteditable=\"false\"
   class=\" W3W  c24 cent\" 
   id=\"w3w:$row[recordID]\" 
   oncontextmenu=\"mapWhat3Words('$row[w3w]');return false; \" 
   onClick=\"empty('w3w:$row[recordID]'); getAPRSLocations('$row[aprs_call], $row[recordID], $row[latitude],$row[longitude],$row[callsign],$row[netID], W3W');\" 
   style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
   <div class='$class' readonly> $row[w3w]  </div> 
</td> 
...
");
?>
```

I've tried using CSS and later JavaScript to add the contenteditable="false" after the field is created, but it too didn't work.
I've tested the issue in Safari, FireFox and Chrome they all behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The contenteditable attribute is used to make elements editable, but setting it to "false" might not prevent focus and editing. To prevent editing, try using the readonly attribute.

```
<?php
echo ("
...
<td $brbCols readonly
   class=\" W3W  c24 cent\" 
   id=\"w3w:$row[recordID]\" 
   oncontextmenu=\"mapWhat3Words('$row[w3w]');return false; \" 
   onClick=\"empty('w3w:$row[recordID]'); getAPRSLocations('$row[aprs_call], $row[recordID], $row[latitude],$row[longitude],$row[callsign],$row[netID], W3W');\" 
   style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
   <div class='$class'> $row[w3w] </div> 
</td> 
...
");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that didn't work either. I also tried with the conteneditable still set to "false".  Both ways failed, I can still write in it.

Comment: your answer did help me find a solution. I added 'readonly' to class=\" readonly W3W c24 cent\" and then wrote a <style>
/* using this to prevent direct editiong to C24 the W3W column */
    .readonly {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use it as a button now . I'll find a way.